# Do plaza and square have a different meaning?

Tags: word-choice

Do *plaza* and *square* have a different meaning, when referring to a place?
From my English studies, I recall that I was taught that plaza and square were two different kinds of "square".

Is it true? Are the words used as synonymous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### square

Wiktionary [says](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/square):

> - An open space in a town, not necessarily square in shape, often containing trees, seating and other features pleasing to the eye.

Wikipedia [describes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square) it as "a public meeting place" and provides two examples:

> - Town square, an open area commonly found in the heart of a traditional town used for community gatherings.
> - Market square, an open area where market stalls are traditionally set out for trading.

### plaza

Wiktionary [says](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plaza):

> plaza (plural plazas)
>
> 1. a town’s public square.
> 2. an open area used for gathering in a city, often having small trees and sitting benches.

Wikipedia is [more verbose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaza):

> In modern usage, a plaza can be any gathering place on a street or between buildings, a street intersection with a statue, etc. Thus contemporary metropolitan landscapes often incorporate the "plaza" as a design element, or as an outcome of zoning regulations, building budgetary constraints, and the like.
>
> [...]
>
> More recently plaza has been used to describe a shopping complex, similar to a shopping mall, borrowing its connotations of a center of cultural life. The name is currently even applied to a single building with some semi-public street-level areas, often with a hotel or office tower above, while mall more often refers to multiple buildings or a street.

Comment: To summarize - yes they're synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

There is essentially no difference between a Plaza and a Square. Both the words are used for Public Spaces and can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Can you post a link that confirms your answer?